# How to set secure rules in Firebase after user has scanned a QR code to read and write to specific database node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would really appreciate some help with this.

I am developing an app which is aimed towards parents and children and I am currently using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Auth.

The parent creates an account using email and password. It then creates a new node in the database using the parent UID as the key for the node.

The parent then generates a QR code which the child can scan using a different device. The QR code contains the database node key. After scanning, the child can now read and write in the same node as the parent.

My question is, how can I/is there anyway I can set secure rules in firebase to allow only the parent and the child that has scanned the QR code to read and write and to prevent my database being exposed?

The child needs to be able to read and write from the parents node as they can't be expected to sign up with an email and password to become authenticated. This is reason I have used a QR code as it is quick and easy for the child to join.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your 'User' table in the Realtime Database you can set a 'permissions' or 'userType' flag with different settings. The settings can then indicate which access the user has.

In the Rules you can then set access assuming the user has the right flag type / setting.

```
"Charges" : {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "(root.child('Groups').child($GroupId).child('CustomerDatabase').child(auth.uid).child('userType').val() == 'admin')"
        }
```

In this example, access to write to the 'Charges' table is restricted to only those users in the 'CustomerDatabase' table where the 'userType' field is set to 'admin'. You can choose multiple user types as follows:

```
"Charges" : {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "(root.child('Groups').child($GroupId).child('CustomerDatabase').child(auth.uid).child('userType').val() == 'admin') 
        || (root.child('Groups').child($GroupId).child('CustomerDatabase').child(auth.uid).child('userType').val() == 'leader')"
 },
```

In this example users have to have EITHER 'admin' OR 'leader' set.